# Print enumerated list of a class

Tags: python

I have written the following code which creates a vector list and then a vector dictionary without the zeros.

```
class SparseVec:     

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.val = [0] * n
        self.len = len(self.val)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

    def __getitem__(self,*i):
        return self.val

    def __setitem__(self, i, n):
        self.val[i] = n
        self.len = max(i, self.len)

         print 'self.len = ', self.len
    def nonzeros(self):
        nonzeroDict = {}
        for i in range(len(self.val)):
            if self.val[i] != 0:
                nonzeroDict[i] = self.val[i]
        return 'Sparse Vector{}'.format(nonzeroDict)
    def __add__(self, other):     
        length = self.len
        result = SparseVec(length)
        if self.len < len(other.val):
            length = len(other.val)
            result = SparseVec(length)        
        for i in range(self.len):
            result[i] = self.val[i] + other.val[i]
        for j in other.val:
            if j not in self.val:
                result[j] = other.val[j]
        return result 

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.val)

if __name__ == '__main__':

      a = SparseVec(5)
      a[2] = 9.2
      a[0] = -1
      a[3] = 0
      print a
      print a.nonzeros()

      b = SparseVec(5)
      b[1] = 1
      print b
      print b.nonzeros()

      c = a+b
      print c
      print c.nonzeros()
```

How can I rewrite the `__str__` method in order to get as a result something like this?

```
print a
[0] = 2  [1] = 5  etc...
```

Also I want this:

```
for ai, i in a:
    print 'a[%d]=%g' % (i, ai)
```

to provide a similar result as above with an a in front of the list index:

```
a[0] = 2 a[1] = 5
```

Comment: Please make the effort to reproduce your indentation properly when posting Python code. If people have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or focus on ones you are not trying to ask about.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You described what you want. So *just do it*?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> val = [2, 5, 7, 9]
>>> '  '.join('[{}] = {}'.format(index, elem)
...           for index, elem in enumerate(val))
'[0] = 2  [1] = 5  [2] = 7  [3] = 9'
```

To have an 'a' in front of each element:

```
>>> '  '.join('a[{}] = {}'.format(index, elem)
...           for index, elem in enumerate(val))
'a[0] = 2  a[1] = 5  a[2] = 7  a[3] = 9'
```

Comment: That works great thanks!
My second problem is that by trying this code  
 for ai, i in a:
    print 'a[%d]=%g' % (i, ai)

I get an error, 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t32.py", line 68, in <module>
    for ai, i in a:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Maybe I should try another way to get this done? For example an iterator in the class?

Comment: @GeoF: `for i, ai in enumerate(a)`

Comment: @GeoF you also have to fix your `__getitem__`: it should read `def __getitem__(self, i): return self.val[i]`